# Retrieving the words from WordNet database

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, wordnet

I’m looking for a website that offers API for retrieving the words from English [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) database.

I do not want to download the WordNet database and implement it in my server.

Simply I want to call API and get back some results in XML format from that web site.
I have a web application in ASP.net that is written in C#.

Here there is a sample from WordNet, I want to do something like that in my web application.

[WordNet Online](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that is no such API publicly available.

According to [Related Projects site](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/#REST) part of WordNet data is avaible as API via [abbreviations.com](http://www.abbreviations.com/api.php):

> Abbreviations.com has created free APIs based on REST calls which return a well-formatted XML result, providing both synonyms and definitions APIs based on the WordNet database.

However on the same page in [.NET/C# section](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/#.NET) you can find some publicly available local APIs, so you don't have to implement it by yourself, but have to download data files.

Comment: As you said, Abbreviations.com returns part of WordNet data but It's very useful and better than nothing :) thanks for useful information. I checked .NET/C# section. I chose the first option (Matt Gerber) and later I transferred to [this page](https://ptl.sys.virginia.edu/msg8u/NLP/Source/ResourceAPIs/WordNet/). I do not know, how to use it. It's very unclear for me. if you have any idea, please let me know. thanks

Comment: It's subversion repository. You have to access it via any subversion client, eg http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ Here you have more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients Also read readme of this project: https://ptl.sys.virginia.edu/msg8u/NLP/Source/ResourceAPIs/WordNet/WordNet/Docs/README.txt

Answer (score 0):

`WordNet` does not seem to expose a `REST` or similar API that can be used. That said, you might be able to derive the URL pattern by searching online and using that in your application and parsing the response html.

You might want to check there website to make sure this is legal.